# How can I maximise Mystic Arte usage by the AI?

Tags: tales-of-berseria

The AI in Tales of Berseria seems to use Mystic Artes (MA) with some regularity but not nearly as often as they should be able to. They often seem to hold on  to 4+ Blast Gauge with a full Soul Gauge (SG) without actually launching a finisher.

I've played around with their Strategy options and setting the final two options to "Mystic Arte" and "When attacking" seems to work, for the most part, but **I was hoping that there was a way to get them to spam MAs often**, especially since I've seen some players mention how they actually disabled MAs for the AI because they were spamming them too quickly. So with that in mind:

1. **What is the most efficient Strategy set-up to force Mystic Artes**?
2. Do different characters require different set-ups?
3. Does the AI actually need to hit the 4-arte or 8-arte combo requirement?
4. Is the issue that they're reluctant to drop below 3 SG while Break Souls are required to reach higher combo chains?
5. Will disabling the Level 1 MA cause them to use their higher level MAs? Or do they use Level 2s at the same rate regardless and am I just missing out on their Level 1s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What is the most efficient Strategy set-up to force Mystic Artes?

For attacking with everything. They don't use them too often if you set it to anything else.

> 2. Do different characters require different set-ups?

Well that depends. Are you going for a good strategic set up? Then yes. If you just want them to use mystic artes all day, then no. See above point.

> 3. Does the AI actually need to hit the 4-arte or 8-arte combo requirement?

Yes

> 4. Is the issue that they're reluctant to drop below 3 SG while Break Souls are required to reach higher combo chains?

No, they will drop below 3 SG if you set them up to do so.

> 5. Will disabling the Level 1 MA cause them to use their higher level MAs? Or do they use Level 2s at the same rate regardless and am I just missing out on their Level 1s?

If you disable the level 1 MA they can not use it during battle. The requirements for the level 2 are basically double to set up in order to use them, so you don't want to disable the level 1 if you want them to use MA sometimes. Sure, the level 2's hit harder, but the requirements are often not met for AI's.